# SQLplus: how to insert only if one of the columns is unique

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-insert

I have a table with 10 columns total, and I need to grab 6 of those columns and insert them into my new table but only if one of those columns is unique.

I understand that:

```
INSERT INTO table_1(col1, col2, col3)
    SELECT DISTINCT colA, colB, colC
    FROM table_2;
```

will give me rows where the combination of A, B, C is unique, but I want to insert only where A is unique and the data that is associated in the other columns of that row.  I've found WHERE EXISTS and GROUP BY but those aren't super clear to me.

I currently am trying...

```
INSERT INTO table_1 (col1, col2, col3)
    SELECT colA, colB, colC
    FROM table_2
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT cola FROM table_2);
```

...cause to me that reads "Insert colA, colB, and colC from table_1 into table_2 if colA does not yet exist in table_2 but I'm not sure if that's correct.  Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by where A is unique.  The requirements make no sense to me.

Comment: I agree with @Hogan. I get that you want to insert unique values from column A and that can easily be done with a GROUP BY, but then you need to decide which values to insert from the other columns or SUM them or something. Need example data?

Answer (score 2):

If by "A is unique" you mean that a given value in "A" has only one value, then you can use this method:

```
INSERT INTO table_1 (col1, col2, col3)
    SELECT colA, MAX(colB), MAX(colC)
    FROM table_2
    GROUP BY colA
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 1;
```

The `HAVING` clause finds the values in "A" that only appear once.  When there is only one row, then `MAX(colB)` and MAX(colC)` return values from that row.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this requirement:

> will give me rows where the combination of A, B, C is unique, but I
>   want to insert only where A is unique and the data that is associated
>   in the other columns of that row.

I'm interpreting your need as only those elements in column A which are singular and then everything from columns B, C, etc... which are found on that same row. If that is the case, I would use [Count](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_count.asp) to define your set first and then join to that set using a subquery.

Here's a way to grab your unique value set:

```
 SELECT colA, Count(colA) as ct
 GROUP BY ColA
 HAVING ct = 1;
```

Then you just join to it:

```
INSERT INTO table_1 (col1, col2, col3,...)
SELECT colA, colB, colC,..
FROM table_2    
JOIN (--Here's your defined set
      SELECT colA, Count(colA) as ct
      GROUP BY ColA
      HAVING ct = 1) sub ON table_2.colA = sub.colA;
```